# eth0 NO-CARRIER on Arch/Wired Connection Not Working

Tags: networking, arch-linux, ethernet, dhcp

The device is a DELL Vostro 1510 and I have tried both the r8169 and r8168 kernel modules. ethtool eth0 shows Auto-negotiation: on MDI-X: Unknown and Link Detected: No. Ip link shows `<NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisk fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000` and I have tried using dhcpcd, nmcli, ip link set eth0 up and numerous other tools to get it running (one running at a time) all to the same outcome.

Dmesg shows eth0 going up and then going down again, once, near boot. lspci definitely shows it using the kernel module correctly (r8168 at this point, r8169 to start with) and this issue is definitely not with the connection or adapter, the connection works with other devices and pinging 127.0.0.1 works.

Comment: what does ifconfig command return?

Comment: i dont seem to have the command ifconfig, is there a package containing it that i should install via usb?

Comment: Use `ip link` instead of `ifconfig`.

Comment: ``1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1 link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 2: eth0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000 link/ether 00:21:70:a7:78:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff``

Comment: Is this at the OS level or are you running Oracle Virtualbox?

If at the OS level, can you print the content of /etc/systemd/network/wired.network and /etc/systemd/network/wireless.network?

If Oracle/VM, what setting are you using? (Bridged, NAT, etc)